# get posted file extension asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I keep getting "Only images are allowed" and I tried "file.PostedFile.FileName" also not working!!

this code is written in a separate class..

```
public static String UploadFile(FileUpload file, String type, out String filename)
{
    String ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    filename = "";
    if (file.PostedFile.ContentLength > 2000000)
    {
        return "File is larger than 2 MB";
    }
    else if (type != "File")
    {
        if (ext.ToLower() != ".jpg" || ext.ToLower() != ".png" || ext.ToLower() != ".gif" || ext.ToLower() != ".jpeg")
        {
            return "Only images are allowed";
        }
        else
        {
            filename = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName() + "_" + file.PostedFile.FileName;
            String root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
            file.SaveAs(root + type + "/" + filename);
            return "Success";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        filename = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName() + "_" + file.PostedFile.FileName;
        String root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
        file.SaveAs(root + filename);
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of fikle are you passing to this method?

Comment: Can you not use File.Extention()

Comment: Check This: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/HttpPostedFileBase-getting-file-extension-in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your condition is wrong, it should be like following:

```
if (ext.ToLower() != ".jpg" && ext.ToLower() != ".png" && ext.ToLower() != ".gif" && ext.ToLower() != ".jpeg")
{
return "Only images are allowed";
}
else
{
///statement
}
```

OR

```
   if (ext.ToLower() == ".jpg" || ext.ToLower() == ".png" || ext.ToLower() == ".gif" || ext.ToLower() == ".jpeg")
    {

    ///statement
    }
    else
    {
return "Only images are allowed";
    }
```

Comment: @Anas .. from the compiler point of view, second one is best, you should use this.

Answer (score 4):

@volpav's answer will fix your problem, but that big `if` isn't the cleanest way to handle the problem.

More elegant would be to define a list of accepted extensions and check to see if `ext` is in the list.  The advantages to this would be that it is easier to maintain if you ever have to change the valid types later, and that you can make extensions user definable if that is desirable.

In the example below I am defining a constant (well readonly variable) for my class that contains an array with all exceptions, and use the `Contains()` extension method to test to see if `ext` exists within it when validating in `UploadFile`

```
public static readonly string[] VALID_EXTENSIONS = 
    new string[4] { ".png", ".jpg", ".gif", ".jpeg" };

// in UploadFile ...
    if (!VALID_EXTENSIONS.Contains(ext.ToLower())) { 
         return "Only images are allowed";
    }
```

By making it static in the above code, I could use this list in the UI to indicate what are excepted extensions, instead of having the user guess what is a valid image type (There are, after all, other image types than those you have included).

Answer (score 3):

Your condition for checking for valid extension is logically incorrect (always evaluates to `true`). It should be like this (`||` are replaced with `&&`):

```
if (ext.ToLower() != ".jpg" && ext.ToLower() != ".png" && ext.ToLower() != ".gif" && ext.ToLower() != ".jpeg")
{
    return "Only images are allowed";
}
```